# Android: Certain intent extras prevent activity finish

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity which allows me to take an image with the camera, and I want to send this image to the parent activity as an Intent extra. However, if I actually try to add the image to the intent, all of a sudden the `finish()` call never seems to do anything and my activity never closes.

Here's some of my code:

```
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c)
    {
        if (imageData != null) {
            // Send the result as a byte array
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("imagedata", imageData);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

The odd thing is, if I comment out the `putExtra()` call then it all works properly (without the image, of course) and my activity closes and I hit the parent's `onActivityResult()` callback. But if I leave the line in, then the activity never closes and the callback never fires.

I've tried putting more trivial things in the extras, like strings, and it's all worked perfectly. `putExtra()` is allowed to take a byte array and I've even tried wrapping it up as a Bitmap and sending that, but it didn't work either. The only thing I can think of is that I'm just not supposed to pass something that big into an Intent, in which case I guess I'll just try writing it to a file instead. It's just that writing is to a file should be slower than just passing the byte array reference around, which is why I'm trying to do it this way.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S
API level: 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be including your image data within the Intent extras. See [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/9309931b3f060284#) for clarification. In a nutshell, keep your Intent extras as small as possible.

I would suggest storing your picture to the SD card, and passing the path to this file in your Intent.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wish I had found that thread two hours ago (new to Android development). It seems a little silly for me to write the image to file and then read it straight back again - maybe I should just use a singleton to hold it, since I only want the image taken to last for the app lifecycle? Anyway, thanks for the prompt response :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public void quit() {
        int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

and call it using quit();