# Android:Problem in passing image and its URI between two activities

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

Can we pass image and an image URI to other activity in same application using bundle?suggest me some way to do that?

**USAGE :**actually i have made an activity that crop an image taken from camera or from image stored in SD card depends upon the user.
and another app that uses a background image and a border image both are overlay so as to see **PHOTOFRAME**.

So now I want to combine both app so that the cropped image come from first app should become the background image for the second app.ie comes in photoframe.How can i do that?

Comment: why do you want to pass an image.. why don't you put it in res directory which android provides...

Comment: Anyway don't pass an image through intent extras. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451202/android-certain-intent-extras-prevent-activity-finish

Comment: You can check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352172/how-do-you-pass-images-bitmaps-between-android-activities-using-bundles

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646979/how-to-pass-image-data-from-one-activity-to-another-activity

Comment: I have passed the Uri of the Image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you save your image in SD card

use this to cal the other activity.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(MyClass.this, TargetClass.class);
final String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
intent.setData(Uri.parse(root + "/my/image/path/image.png"));
startActivity(intent);
```

if you are the reciever then you can get the path by calling

```
Uri path = getIntent().getData();
```

in the **onCreate** of the recieving activity. this is the standard way of checking for path by other activities.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pass URI object,see putParcelable method in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html, URI already implements Parcelable interface,you can use corresponding get methods to get it.If any object that implements Parcelable interface then we can pass it using Bundle.