# how to get an URI from a Bundle?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, uri, android-bundle

I got an Intent that takes a photo, after taking the photo I get the bundle with

```
this.imagen = imageReturnedIntent; 
this.lol = imagen.getExtras();
```

I got my "extra" on the Bundle, but I need it in a Uri because after getting the "data" I send it to an AsynTask:

```
UploadDatabaseAsyncTask async = new UploadDatabaseAsyncTask();
async.execute(data); // Where "data" should be the Uri
```

**Edit:** I tried to get the Uri like this but the data is null

```
intent.getdata();
```

Comment: What type of data are you working with? Are you sure a uri is the best option?

Comment: Maybe this old post is something for you ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921906/androidproblem-in-passing-image-and-its-uri-between-two-activities